# Self generate SSL Certificate for IIS6?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, certificate

Hi guys is it possible to create your own SSL cert for IIS 6? If so does anyone have a link to a good guide on the web?

Thank!

John

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yep, its pretty straight forward:

1. Download and install the [IIS 6 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&DisplayLang=en)
2. Select SelfSSL from the start menu, under programs->IIS Resources
3. Read the instructions shown at the command prompt

To generate the cert, run selfssl with any of the options you need selected, an example command would be:

```
selfssl /N:CN=www.site.com /K:1024 /S:2874 /P:443 /V:365
```

This will create a cert for www.site.com, with a key size of 1024, for site 2874 in IIS, on port 443, valid for one year.

Note that this certificate will not be initially trusted by any browsers, as you are not a trusted authority.

Comment: Great! I used this answer a few times already. Today I discovered that the link to IIS 6 Resource Kit broke, and I couldn't find any other official download page that works on Microosft's site (even the links inside Microsoft are broken for this...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a self-signed cert? You could use the [IIS6 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&DisplayLang=en)'s SelfSSL tool: see http://www.somacon.com/p42.php.

Comment: This link should be removed, as it's been hijacked by a spam site.

Comment: Yes, I have done so. Though not sure there's any point in this answer any more anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use X509Builder at http://www.we-coffee.com/x509builder.aspx