# self-signed certificate for iis 6.0

Tags: iis, ssl, wildcard

how do i setup a self-signed certificate for multiple websites?

Answer (score 2):

#### See also

- [How to create a self-signed wildcard
  SSL certificate for IIS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474609/how-to-create-a-self-signed-wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-iis-6)
- [Self
  generate SSL Certificate for
  IIS6?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40923/self-generate-ssl-certificate-for-iis6)

Answer (score 1):

[This Article](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Securing-Exchange-Server-2003-Outlook-Web-Access-Chapter5.html) deals with creating certificates for exchange but the process is similar for any IIS Website. Hope that helps!