# IIS6 cannot accept SSL connection

Tags: iis-6

I have a server on a network I used SelfSSL to generate the certificate when I tick "Require Secure communication" option in a website security tab, the web site cannot be opened anymore.

using https protocol, I got 403 error

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self generate SSL Certificate for IIS6?](http://serverfault.com/questions/40923/self-generate-ssl-certificate-for-iis6)

Comment: Prior to checking "Require Secure Communication" did you verify that the site works using https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us the substatus error code? That will take a lot of the guess work out of figuring out what exactly isn't working.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/ad20e45c-7771-4039-b6f0-30544474f0da.mspx?mfr=true